# date picker with default time in apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I need to create date picker with default time in it. Please suggest how it can be done in Apex.

Date can be changed but time should be set to same value.

I created date picker with time but I could not able to make it as default value in time field.

Comment: You arent actually using a default time, you are doing a set time. So how about having the date picker just be for the date, and then before saving into the DB, do a process to set the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your date picker returns a standard Oracle date then just truncate it and add the interval representing the fixed time you want. For example: assume you want the fixed time to be 8AM then

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss' -- set for display of result only
with picker as (select sysdate as pd from dual)  -- return from date picker
select pd, trunc(pd) + interval '8' hour from picker;  -- return date with fixed time
```

Note: the alter session is for display of the result only. It does not actually effect the result.
I don't use Apex but I think the same can be accomplished by:

```
picked_date := trunc(pd) + interval '8' hour;
```

or similar.